# How to use admonitions in nbsphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, nbsphinx

I'm currently using the `jupyter-sphinx` extention in my documentation to execute code. I'm dealing at the same time with Google services authentication which have proven to be dificult using this extention. I tested it with `nbsphinx` which have proven being more reliable when dealing with .config parameters. The only thing I'm missing from my rst file is the admonitions.

Given the following paragraph wriiten in rst:

```
.. warning::

    The names of countries are all unique but not the smaller administrative layers.
```

How could I write down the same thing in a notebook markdown cell to be correctly interpreted by `nbsphinx` ?

Comment: See https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.2/a-normal-rst-file.html#sphinx-directives-for-info-warning-boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admonitions are not per-se supported in notebooks yet (https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1292) so not supported in nbsphinx either.

A experimental workaround exists for both "info" and "warning" admonitions and is described in [@mzjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651/mzjn) link to the documentation: https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.2/a-normal-rst-file.html#sphinx-directives-for-info-warning-boxes

````
 <div class="alert alert-warning">

    **Warning:** This is an *experimental feature*!

    Its usage will probably change in the future or it might be removed completely!

    </div>
```
````